# cheapest UPS for pi4

Tags: pi-4, battery, usb-c

I am looking for a better/cheaper way to do power-backup in case of blackouts.

Right now it is a PI4 I need to power, and it is powered by a 12V AGM battery (12Ah)

PI4 <-> USB-C cable <-> USB-C car charger <-> 12V car outlet/connecter <-> fuse and wires <-> AGM-battery <-> cheap battery charger

Is there a simpler/cheaper way to convert from the AGM+charger power (12-ish Volts to 13.7 Volts) to the USB-C 15W power needed by the PI4 than by using the "car-parts" that cost and take up space?

Comment: In theory you could use a off the shelf USB style battery pack with 'Pass through' so that it can charge at the same time as providing output power.   

But the challenge is finding one that switches from passthrough to battery power without interrupting the output power.

I've toyed with adding a capacitor but then I think maybe I'd be better off with a fully fledged UPS. ;-)

Comment: The battery packs I could find that supply enough power for PI4 are somewhat expensive AND have a 10+ hour recharge time, so while simple and cheap enough they seem to have some limitations.

Comment: For a Pi Zero I have usd a cheap battery pack (2000mAh or so) that one works perfectly and keeps the pi running without pause when the main power i cut.

Comment: Used a Varta battery pack without problems; otherwise, there is an UPS hat with 3Ah Lipolymer battery.